# Exception with Foreign Key in MVC project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to record a new entry on a table (HistoryRequestResponse), which one of the values is a foreign key to another table (HistoryRequests). I know for sure that the foreign key value (lets say 1090) exists on HistoryRequests, but when i permorm the db.SaveChanges() I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__HistoryRe__idReq__04AFB25B". The conflict occurred in database
>   "iDesk", table "dbo.HistoryRequests", column 'id'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

```
public partial class HistoryRequestResponse
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int idReq { get; set; }
        public string submitUser { get; set; }
        public string respType { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime submitDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ResponseType ResponseType { get; set; }
        public virtual HistoryRequests HistoryRequests { get; set; }
    }

public partial class HistoryRequests
    {
        public HistoryRequests()
        {
            this.HistoryRequestResponse = new HashSet<HistoryRequestResponse>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime submitDate { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> closeDate { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
        public string submitUser { get; set; }
        public string responsible { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> serialNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> area { get; set; }

        public virtual Area Area1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Computers Computers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HistoryRequestResponse> HistoryRequestResponse { get; set; }
        public virtual Priorities Priorities { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I do the following in the POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Reopen(int? id, string resp)
        {
            HistoryRequests request = db.HistoryRequests.Find(id);
            try
            {
                var response = new HistoryRequestResponse()
                {
                    respType = "Reabrir",
                    //HistoryRequests = request,
                    id = 0,
                    submitDate = DateTime.Now,
                    submitUser = User.Identity.Name,
                    description = resp
                };

                response.idReq = (int)id;
                request.closeDate = null;
                request.responsible = User.Identity.Name;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.HistoryRequestResponse.Add(response);
                    db.SaveChanges(); //WHERE I GET THE EXCEPTION
                    db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    var email = from u in db.Users
                                where u.UserName.Equals(request.submitUser)
                                select u.Email;
                    //SmtpServer.SendEmail(email.SingleOrDefault(), requests.title, desc);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "BHome");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Content("Erro ao reabrir o pedido");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged and verified that response.idReq is in fact getting assigned a value that has a corresponding value in the ID column of the historyrequests table? Also, we'd probably want to look at what the HistoryRequestResponse.Add method is doing exactly.

Comment: You are inserting a foreign key that doesn't exist in your table.